# link_to is not redirecting to proper position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, hyperlink, anchor

I am using rails 3.1.3.

In a single page (large page), some sections are there which are separated by different  ids.

Using `link_to` tag, I am not able to go to particular section. I have written code like below,

In one partial,

```
<%= link_to "Summary", "#DIV_SUMMARY_INDEX" %>
<%= link_to "Objectives", "#DIV_OBJECTIVES_INDEX" %>
```

In another partial,

```
<div id="DIV_SUMMARY_INDEX">
  <%= render :partial => "/feeds/cv/summary" %>
</div>

<div id="DIV_OBJECTIVES_INDEX">
  <%= render :partial => "/feeds/cv/objectives" %>
</div>
```

Now these both partial's are displaying in a single page.
So, according to my logic, when I click on 'Summary/Objectives' link, it should go to `DIV_SUMMARY_INDEX / DIV_OBJECTIVES_INDEX` div section but now it is not happening.

Actually we used iframe tag to load whole page.

Below method is also not working,

```
<%= link_to "Summary", "#",  :anchor => "DIV_SUMMARY_INDEX" %>
<%= link_to "Objectives", "#", :anchor => "DIV_OBJECTIVES_INDEX" %>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: you have to do this via javascript, check the div id and then show or hide the div

Answer (score 0):

Its `<%= link_to(<link name>, :anchor => <div_id>) %>`

Ex: `<%= link_to('Click here', :anchor => 'job_list') %>` #=> job_list is my div id

I checked with rails 3.2.9 and works

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Summary", "#",  :anchor => "DIV_SUMMARY_INDEX" %>
<%= link_to "Objectives", "#", :anchor => "DIV_OBJECTIVES_INDEX" %>
```

try this